# Outlook Distribution List and WSS 3

Tags: list, wss-3.0, outlook, contacts

Having a devil of a time figuring out definitively whether Outlook Distribution Lists can be saved within a Contact list under Sharepoint.

Here's the scenario:

Server runs WSS 3.0. Workstation runs Outlook 2010. The Contacts list is connected to Outlook. (In this test environment, the connecting user has FC on the site and is a Collection Admin.)

I'd like to be able to create a single item, a Distribution List ("Contact Group" in Outlook 2010 parlance) that contains several other Contacts as members. So, naturally, I'd be able to start a new email and add the Sharepoint-saved distribution list into the TO/CC/BCC field(s).

Trying to create distribution lists in Outlook simply produces errors about permissions. I suspect it's not *really* a permissions issue.

I've read a few things out on the Web about this. Two options appeared a couple of times...

OPTION #1: Create different contact lists within your site and each one becomes a distribution list of sorts. If someone wants to email the members, they connect the list to Outlook, open it, select all members, and then send a mail to them.

OPTION #2: Connect your site Contacts list into Outlook. Create a new subfolder within Outlook underneath the Sharepoint list. Create a distribution list and save it within the folder.

Option 1 is possible, though I'll have to add Contacts to Lists via the Sharepoint web site and then synchronize all those Lists to Outlook presuming I need access to all the lists. Plus, I don't get the benefit of a single entry within the TO/CC/BCC field(s).

Option 2 may be simply wrong, at least I've not been able to implement it. I can create a folder with the Contacts list via the Sharepoint web UI. (I've added the New Folder option under the Advanced settings.) However, that folder does not show up in Outlook. I also cannot create a new folder under the Sharepoint list within Outlook even though I have write permissions.

I thought about creating a mail-enabled Distribution List within AD, but I understand that Sharepoint will not work with DLs, only Security Groups. Furthermore, my Exchange/AD environment is at a hosted company, so the twain really don't meet.

Any ideas, o' savers of my hide?

Cheers,

m

Comment: If it's not a user or a mail-enabled security group, the only other option I can think of is a customization where an email is send to a defined email address. You can't add contacts or DLs within SharePoint.